# Search the Facebook UserName in Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where I can link the user account with Facebook. So far so good, but I need a value that identifies the Facebook user, as the name, but that is unique. So I thought of `user name` that is unique per account. But I found no information in the Facebook documents that show how to get this information. Does anyone know how I can get this? And it is not the name that the user puts in his profile, it is the username.

Comment: You can't. Use User ID.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (and the best way to store) is by the use of User IDs. Facebook allows you to do this.

User: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

*I personally don't use Facebook API but from experience you would use an User ID.*